# Java Swing show tooltip as a message dialog

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

Is it possible in Java Swing to show message box using tooltip item. I need to show tooltip not only when a mouse hovers some component but also when I choose specific item in context menu of this component when tooltips are turned off.

Comment: Tooltips and message boxes are two different things, I know of no way of using one in the place of the other. If your favourite search engine didn’t turn anything up, it’s probably impossible and you would need to consider your alternatives.

Showing a message box in response to selecting an item from a context menu, I would expect this to be straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PopupFactory to show your popup message

```
    final Popup p = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(myComponent, new JLabel("Here is my popup!"), x, y);
    p.show();
    // create a timer to hide the popup later
    Timer t = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            p.hide();

        }
    });
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();
```

where myComponent - is the component for which popup must be shown

x, y - coordinates of popup.

Comment: That's great! Thank you.

Comment: I just a little bit improve:

Comment: JToolTip toolTip = new JToolTip();        
        toolTip.setTipText("my text");
        final Popup popup = popupFactory.getPopup(myComponent, toolTip, x, y);
        popup.show();